# Union two identical collection from two different DBs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js, mongodb-query

I’ve asked to combine two collections with identical objects form, the problem is there is a couple of different Dbs that I need to pull the collections from, I didn’t see a clear solution for this so I would be glad if someone has crossed into it, thanks.

collections:

"stack_validation" in the first DB:

```json
[{
  "_id": "03fc2e61c0d6e351437ffd65820cd387",
  "clu_ids": [
    "637E5C41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
  ],
  "clus_validation_ids": [
    {
      "$ref": "validation_clus",
      "$id": "637E5C41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
    }
  ],
  "status": "New",
  "last_data_date": null,
  "date_updated": null,
  "flags": {
    "flag1": false,
    "flag2": false,
    "flag3": false,
    "flag4": false
  },
  "notes": [
    "This is a demo note for Stack"
  ]
},{
  "_id": "03fc2e61c0d6e3asdsa51437ffd65820cd387",
  "clu_ids": [
    "637E5C41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
  ],
  "clus_validation_ids": [
    {
      "$ref": "validation_clus",
      "$id": "637E5Ca41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
    }
  ],
  "status": "New",
  "last_data_date": null,
  "date_updated": null,
  "flags": {
    "flag1": false,
    "flag2": false,
    "flag3": false,
    "flag4": false
  },
  "notes": [
    "This is a demo note for Stack"
  ]
}]
```

"stack_validation" is in the second DB:

```
[{
  "_id": "03fcasd2e61c0d6e351437ffd65820cd387",
  "clu_ids": [
    "637E5C41-43A8-41D3-das9627-5D9A33028179"
  ],
  "clus_validation_ids": [
    {
      "$ref": "validation_clus",
      "$id": "637E1235C41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
    }
  ],
  "status": "New",
  "last_data_date": null,
  "date_updated": null,
  "flags": {
    "flag1": false,
    "flag2": false,
    "flag3": false,
    "flag4": false
  },
  "notes": [
    "This is a demo note for Stack"
  ]
},{
  "_id": "03fc2e61c0d6e351437ffd65820cd387",
  "clu_ids": [
    "637E2121d41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
  ],
  "clus_validation_ids": [
    {
      "$ref": "validation_clus",
      "$id": "637E52131-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
    }
  ],
  "status": "New",
  "last_data_date": null,
  "date_updated": null,
  "flags": {
    "flag1": false,
    "flag2": false,
    "flag3": false,
    "flag4": false
  },
  "notes": [
    "This is a demo note for Stack"
  ]
}]
```

Expected result both of the collections("stack_validation") combined:

```
[{
  "_id": "03fcasd2e61c0d6e351437ffd65820cd387",
  "clu_ids": [
    "637E5C41-43A8-41D3-das9627-5D9A33028179"
  ],
  "clus_validation_ids": [
    {
      "$ref": "validation_clus",
      "$id": "637E1235C41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
    }
  ],
  "status": "New",
  "last_data_date": null,
  "date_updated": null,
  "flags": {
    "flag1": false,
    "flag2": false,
    "flag3": false,
    "flag4": false
  },
  "notes": [
    "This is a demo note for Stack"
  ]
},{
  "_id": "03fc2e61c0d6e351437ffd65820cd387",
  "clu_ids": [
    "637E2121d41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
  ],
  "clus_validation_ids": [
    {
      "$ref": "validation_clus",
      "$id": "637E52131-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
    }
  ],
  "status": "New",
  "last_data_date": null,
  "date_updated": null,
  "flags": {
    "flag1": false,
    "flag2": false,
    "flag3": false,
    "flag4": false
  },
  "notes": [
    "This is a demo note for Stack"
  ]
},{
  "_id": "03fc2e61c0d6e351437ffd65820cd387",
  "clu_ids": [
    "637E5C41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
  ],
  "clus_validation_ids": [
    {
      "$ref": "validation_clus",
      "$id": "637E5C41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
    }
  ],
  "status": "New",
  "last_data_date": null,
  "date_updated": null,
  "flags": {
    "flag1": false,
    "flag2": false,
    "flag3": false,
    "flag4": false
  },
  "notes": [
    "This is a demo note for Stack"
  ]
},{
  "_id": "03fc2e61c0d6e3asdsa51437ffd65820cd387",
  "clu_ids": [
    "637E5C41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
  ],
  "clus_validation_ids": [
    {
      "$ref": "validation_clus",
      "$id": "637E5Ca41-43A8-41D3-9627-5D9A33028179"
    }
  ],
  "status": "New",
  "last_data_date": null,
  "date_updated": null,
  "flags": {
    "flag1": false,
    "flag2": false,
    "flag3": false,
    "flag4": false
  },
  "notes": [
    "This is a demo note for Stack"
  ]
}]
```

I've tried to use operators such as `$unionWith`, `$lookup`, and `$merge`, but none of them actually answer the requirements am I missing something?

My solution:
After consideration, I found out that "atlas data-federation" is suitable for what I need I found out there isn't an easy solution to aggregate through all of the DBs so I left with this choice. I couldn't really create a DB with all the collections combined due to security measures
check this out: [atlas-data-federation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/overview/)

Comment: Would you show some example collections/documents and the desired output?

Comment: $unionWith and $lookup only work with collections in the same database.

Comment: If this is on MongoDB Atlas you could create a [Data Lake](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/data-lake) and query across databases.  Otherwise, I think you may need to move/copy these collections into a single database to perform your operations.

Comment: You can first [$out](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to either one of your databases to create a clone of either of your collections. Then you can do the `$unionWith` as normal.